# Dafny. Prove that all values from an interval appear in seq

Tags: seq, dafny

I try to prove the following lemma. It seems really trivial, but I can't manage to prove it. Thank you in advance!

```
lemma test(x : seq<int>)
  // if the values from x are margined by an interval
  // the values are different
  // and the number of values equals the size of the interval
  // then all values from the interval appear in x

  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==> 
    0 <= x[i] < |x|;

  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==>
   forall i' :: 0 <= i' < |x| && i != i' ==>
     x[i] != x[i'];

  ensures forall v :: 0 <= v < |x| ==>
    exists i :: 0 <= i < |x| && x[i] == v;
{

}
```

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/d8VK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using some facts about set cardinalities.

```
lemma test(x : seq<int>)
  // if the values from x are margined by an interval
  // the values are different
  // and the number of values equals the size of the interval
  // then all values from the interval appear in x

  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==> 
    0 <= x[i] < |x|;

  requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |x| ==>
   forall i' :: 0 <= i' < |x| && i != i' ==>
     x[i] != x[i'];

  ensures forall v :: 0 <= v < |x| ==> v in x
{
    var L: set<int>, R: set<int> := {}, RangeSet(0, |x|);
    var i := 0;
    CardinalityRangeSet(0, |x|);
    while i < |x|
        invariant 0 <= i <= |x|
        invariant L == set j | 0 <= j < i :: x[j]
        invariant forall v | v in L :: v in x
        invariant forall v | 0 <= v < |x| :: v in L || v in R
        invariant |R| == |x| - i

    {
        L, R := L + {x[i]}, R - {x[i]};
        i := i + 1;
    }
}

predicate InRange(lo: int, hi: int, i: int)
{
    lo <= i < hi
}

function RangeSet(lo: int, hi: int): set<int>
{
    set i | lo <= i < hi && InRange(lo, hi, i)
}

lemma CardinalityRangeSet(lo: int, hi: int)
    decreases hi - lo
    ensures |RangeSet(lo, hi)| == if lo >= hi then 0 else hi - lo
{
    if lo < hi {
        assert RangeSet(lo, hi) == {lo} + RangeSet(lo + 1, hi);
        CardinalityRangeSet(lo + 1, hi);
    }
}
```

I changed your specification slightly to use the Dafny syntax `v in x`, which is equivalent to what you wrote, and a little easier for Dafny to reason about.

The basic idea of the proof is to start with the range `R` of elements `0..|x|`, and then iteratively remove elements `x[i]` from `R` and add them to `L`. This maintains the invariant that every number in the range `0..|x|` is either in `L` or `R`, while the cardinality of `R` decreases on every iteration. Thus, at the end of the loop `R` is empty, so every number in the range must be in `L`, and therefore in `x`.

I also used one helper lemma proved by induction to show that `RangeSet` has the expected size.

(Edited to get rid of "No terms found to trigger on" warning in `RangeSet`. Introducing the predicate `InRange` gives it something to trigger on, but you still need to include the explicit range in `RangeSet` because otherwise it can't figure that the set is finite.)

Comment: Thank you for your fast and complex response!

Comment: Any idea how to eliminate the `/!\ No terms found to trigger on.` for RangeSet?

Comment: @AndriciCezar I edited my answer to fix the warning (and a subsequent error).